# How do I make my checkbox hamburger menu work correctly?

Tags: html, css, sass, responsive-design, hamburger-menu

I'm trying to create a pure css hamburger menu. I have done this in the past before, but can't get it to work now. I can get the hamburger animations working when checked, but can't get the menu to become visible when checked. I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

P.S. I know this code is a mess and I'm sorry.

HTML:

```
    <nav>
        <div class="navwrapper">
            <p class="fancy">AL</p>

            <div>
                <input class="nav-toggle" type="checkbox" id="nav-toggle" />
                <label class="menu-icon" for="nav-toggle"
                    ><span class="navicon"></span
                ></label>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
            </div>

            <ul class="menu">
                <li class="menu-item">
                    <a href="./index.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item">
                    <a href="./about.html">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item">
                    <a href="./projects.html">Projects</a>
                    <ul class="menu-dropdown">
                        <li class="menu-item dropdown-item">
                            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="menu-item dropdown-item">
                            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="menu-item dropdown-item">
                            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item">
                    <a href="./reflection.html">Reflection</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item">
                    <a href="#project.html">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-background"></div>
    </nav>
```

CSS:

```
nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #30475e;
}

.navwrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    max-width: 1360px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    p {
        margin: 0 0 0 16px;
    }
    div {
        display: none;
    }
    .menu {
        display: flex;
        margin: 0;
        list-style: none;
        padding: 16px 0;
        &-item {
            margin: 0 16px;
            background-color: #f05454;
            text-align: center;
            position: relative;
            box-shadow: 4px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
            transition: all ease-in-out 100ms;
            a {
                display: block;
                text-decoration: none;
                color: black;
                font-weight: 700;
                font-size: 16px;
                padding: 8px 16px;
                width: 120px;
                border: solid #f05454 4px;
                transition: all ease-in-out 100ms;
            }
            &:hover {
                > ul {
                    visibility: visible;
                    background-color: #30475e;
                    opacity: 1;
                }
                a {
                    transition: all ease-in-out 100ms;
                    color: white;
                }
                background-color: transparent;
            }
        }
        &-dropdown {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: space-evenly;
            align-items: center;
            visibility: hidden;
            list-style: none;
            padding: 16px 16px;
            position: absolute;
            height: 220px;
            width: 180px;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translateX(-50%);
            transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
            opacity: 0;
            z-index: 3;
        }
    }
    @media (max-width: 1000px) {
        div {
            display: block;
            margin: 8px 16px 0 0;
            label {
                visibility: hidden;
            }
            input {
                display: block;
                width: 40px;
                height: 32px;
                cursor: pointer;
                opacity: 0;
                z-index: 2;
                position: absolute;
                &:checked ~ span {
                    opacity: 1;
                    transform: rotate(45deg);
                    &:nth-last-child(2) {
                        opacity: 0;
                        transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.2, 0.2);
                    }
                    &:nth-last-child(1) {
                        transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-2px, -3px);
                    }
                }
            }
            span {
                display: block;
                width: 33px;
                height: 4px;
                margin-bottom: 5px;
                position: relative;
                background: #f05454;
                border-radius: 3px;
                z-index: 1;
                transform-origin: 4px 0px;
                transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1),
                    background 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1),
                    opacity 0.55s ease;
                &:first-child {
                    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
                }
                &:nth-last-child(2) {
                    transform-origin: 0% 100%;
                }
            }
        }
        .menu {
            position: absolute;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            z-index: 30;
            opacity: 1;
            transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1);
            right: 0;
            top: 64px;
            display: none;
            padding: 0 16px 16px;
            background-color: #30475e;
            li {
                margin: 16px 0 0;
                width: 300px;
                a {
                    width: 100%;
                }
                ul {
                    display: none;
                }
                &:hover {
                    background-color: #30475e;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// TEMP
.fancy {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #f05454;
    filter: drop-shadow(4px 4px 0px #000);
    margin-left: 16px;
}

.nav-background {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 10px;
    left: 0;
    height: 160px;
    z-index: -1;
    background-image: linear-gradient(1deg, transparent 0 50%, #30475e 50.5%);
}
```